# bad performing mysql query for click reporting

Tags: php, mysql

i have build a simple php site for click reporting from yourls link shortener. First of all i have to extract  "subids" from  long urls in the url table then group by subids, extract the keywords. with the keywords i loop through the logtable and count every click. The logTable has a few Million entries and the url table a few 100k entries. So actually i need about 5 minutes to calculate one day... so it's not really working...

this snippet actually do the work:

```
$sql_get_keyword="SELECT keyword FROM yourls_url WHERE url LIKE '%_".$track_id."_%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
    $qry_get_keyword=mysqli_query($link, $sql_get_keyword);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_get_keyword)) {
    $keywords[]=$row['keyword'];
    };  
    $sql = "
            select 
            substring_index(substring_index(url, IF(LOCATE('?tag=',url),'?tag=', '&tag='), -1),'-21', 1) Tag,
            (case
                        WHEN length(substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1)) = 8 AND substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1) REGEXP '^[0-9]_'  THEN SUBSTRING(substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1), 3, 6)
                                    WHEN length(substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1)) = 8 AND substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1) REGEXP '^.{6}_[0-9]$' THEN LEFT(substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1), 6)
                                    WHEN length(substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1)) = 5 AND substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1) REGEXP '^.{3}_[0-9]$' THEN LEFT(substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1), 3)
                                    WHEN length(substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1)) = 6 AND substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1) REGEXP '^.{4}_[0-9]$' THEN LEFT(substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1), 4)
                                    WHEN length(substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1)) = 7 AND substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1) REGEXP '^.{5}_[0-9]$' THEN LEFT(substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1), 5)
                        ELSE substring_index(url, 'subtag=', -1)    
                END
                ) AS subid,
            SUM((SELECT COUNT(click_time)
                                FROM yourls_log  
                                WHERE yourls_log.shorturl = yourls_url.keyword 
                                AND ".$dateClause.")) klicks 
            FROM 
                yourls_url 
            WHERE
            (SELECT COUNT(click_time)
                                FROM yourls_log  
                                WHERE yourls_log.shorturl = yourls_url.keyword AND
                                    ".$dateClause.") > 0
            AND substring_index(substring_index(url, IF(LOCATE('?tag=',url),'?tag=', '&tag='), -1),'-21', 1) NOT Like 'it%'
            GROUP BY subid
            ORDER BY klicks DESC";
```

i have allready set an Index on "shorturl" but this has not really an effect. Has anybody an idea what i should do to speed that up without changing the structure of the database?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: Everything in this query screams trouble. If you want your queries fast you need to structure your schema so you can group on an indexed column. Computing values like this can be painfully slow at query time. If possible, do these transformations in advance and persist them in columns set aside for this task.

Comment: Thank you. The Problem is that i can't change the structure. but i'll try with prepared statements thanks for that info.

Comment: You may find that creating a temporary table with the right indexes as an intermediate step helps considerably here.

Comment: Can you show [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) command for your query?

Comment: Gosh, it's no use for explain, with such an unoptimized query. the guy should learn **normalization** and **joins** first, to get rid of that substring and sub-select craze